# Spring JPA select one column doesn't work

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jhipster

I need to retrieve all the records for players column in sports table. SportsRepository method like below.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")                                   
@Repository                                                              
public interface SportsRepository extends JpaRepository<Sport, Long> {   
  public static final String GET_Players="SELECT players FROM Sport"; 
  @Query(value = GET_Players, nativeQuery = true)
  public static List<String> getPlayers();                                                   
}
```

After that I type "gradlew clean test" and see. Then it will generate an error saying "error: missing method body, or declare abstract". Why is that? Do we need to implement the body. Because JPA query should give the output as I could understand. Please anyone knows?

Comment: Could you post your Sport class definition?

Comment: That means entity class of the Sport know? @inafalcao

Comment: Yes. I want to see the Sport class attributes.

Comment: Maybe you don't even need the @Query, you could do it with naming convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a JAVA [**interface**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html), when you try to define a static method, you should give it a method body, but here I think the only thing you should do is remove `static` from your method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")                                   
@Repository                                                              
public interface SportsRepository extends JpaRepository<Sport, Long> {   
    public static final String GET_Players="SELECT players FROM Sport"; 
    @Query(value = GET_Players, nativeQuery = true)
    public List<String> getPlayers();                                                   
}
```

Also access modifier `public` is not necessary here as well, because java take `public` as default when define a method in interface.

**Note:** I noticed that you assigned `nativeQuery` with `true`, you should confirm the `GET_Players` is sql, not a jql.

Comment: @M.David sql means table or column name is from your actual db, not your entity name or entity field name.

Comment: Noted @Forward. How to implement test method for above code?